# print only the numbers that the user entered and is strictly less than average

Tags: java

So now the average is calculated, I am trying to print out the user input ,in its own line only which are strictly less than the average. I tried doing this but, go an error"bad operands for binary operator "<" .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class avg
    {
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter some numbers(Ctrl-d to quit):");
            double[] myArray = new double[10];
            int howMany = 0;
            double sum=0 ;
            double avg=0;
            while (in.hasNextDouble()) // Ctrl-D to terminate
            {
                double userVal = in.nextDouble();
                myArray[howMany++] = userVal;

                if ( howMany >= myArray.length )
                {
                    //myArray.length = myArray.length * 2;
                    double[] tempArray = new double[2 * myArray.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
                        tempArray[i] = myArray[i];
                    myArray = tempArray;        
                }
            }
            for (int i = howMany - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
            sum += myArray[i];
            }
            avg = sum/howMany;
            System.out.print("Average: "+ avg);
            System.out.println(myArray<avg);// to print numbers that the user entered only which are strictly less than the avg. This did not work//

    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(myArray, 0, howMany).average().getAsDouble()`

Comment: So sir do u want me to add this statement after the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = howMany - 1; i >= 0; i--){
     sum+=myArray[i];//sum up the array
}
avg = sum / howMany;
```

To print each `double` in one line:

```
System.out.println(avg);

for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
    if(myArray[i] < avg){
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);//single line for every double
    }
}
```

print all `double`s in one line:

```
String oneLine = "["; 
int lowerAvg = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
if(myArray[i] < avg){
        oneLine += (i > 0 && ++lowerAvg > 0)?", ":""; // add separator
        oneLine += (myArray[i]);
    }
}
oneLine+="]";
System.out.println(oneLine);//prints like [1.0, 2.0, ...]
```

**Using Java 8:**

```
avg = Arrays.stream(myArray, 0, howMany).average().orElse(0);
final double finalAvg = avg;//final variable to use in filter condition
System.out.println(finalAvg);
Arrays.stream(myArray, 0, howMany).filter(x -> x < finalAvg).forEach(System.out::println);//will print every double in a single line
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(myArray, 0, howMany).filter(x -> x < finalAvg).toArray()));//Will print the array like [1.0, 2.0, ...]
```

Comment: No need to check `isPresent()`, just do `orElse(0)` or `orElse(avg)`.

Comment: thanks, it works great. Another question, so what if i wanted to print the numbers entered in by the user in the output followed by the average. For example: AVERAGE : 12 (followed by the numbers the user entered before) x(nxtline) y (nextline)

Comment: i tried doing this `System.out.println(myArray[i])` followed by the avg statement , but it din work

Comment: What exactly did not work. You can add your code in your question so we know what you have tried

Comment: I just added what i have done for that step in my code, along with question sir @Jérôme

Comment: It gives an error "cannot find symbol - variable Arrays"

Comment: So you're not using java 8. I will add the other code in some seconds

Comment: Yes Sir, I am not using Java 8

Comment: Actually `Arrays` is supported since Java 5.

Comment: Thankyou so much that worked!! Apart from this just curious to know, if i want to like get each number on a new by itself, do I add `\n`

Comment: Add `\n` or do `System.out.println();`

Comment: It did work though! because Im supposed to  print off the array numbers like 1,the next number in a newline 2 and then the next line 3 and then next 4 instead of [1,2,3,4] as a string

Comment: Please take the upper example 'To print each` double` in one line:'